# I am unable to create an App Package in the Developer Portal for my Chatbot

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I have created a Bot in the Azure Portal and then I am trying to create an App Package in the Teams Developer Portal. I have given all the required details but when I click on "Publish to Store", I am getting the following error:

"*Provided add-in package was not understood. Please, make sure that the file being submitted is a valid Office add-in package.*"

I did R&D and others also got the same issue but no where I didn't find the correct solution to resolve this issue. It became a show stopper for us to publish our chatbot in the Teams Store.

Could anyone Please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to publish to main app store, for worldwide public consumption, or just for use within your company?

Comment: Could you please download app package from [Publish] button in top-right of the window, and click [Download the app package]. then sideload the app package and check if you are getting same error? Also check the apppackage folder consist any other folder?